# multiple user authentication in django rest framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

my code

```
models.py
class User(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    phone_no = models.CharField(unique=True,  null=True,max_length=10)
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    # type_choice = (
    #     ('photographer', 'Photographer'),
    #     ('customer','Customer'),
    # )
    is_customer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_photographer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    #user_type = models.CharField(choices = type_choice,max_length=20,default="customer")
    auth_provider = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False, default=AUTH_PROVIDERS.get('email'))
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    objects = CustomUserManager() 
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
    def tokens(self):
        refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(self)
        return {
            'refresh': str(refresh),
            'access': str(refresh.access_token)
        }
serializer.py
class UserSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'first_name','last_name','phone_no','email','password','is_photographer',
                  'is_customer']
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password' :{'write_only':True}  #  to does not return password in api ## postman
        }
    # convert password to hash key
    def create(self, validated_data):
        password = validated_data.pop('password',None)
        instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
        if password is not None:
            instance.set_password(password)
        if len(password) <6:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("entre strong password")
        instance.save()
        return instance
    
# login serializers

class UserLoginSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(max_length=255, min_length=3)
    password = serializers.CharField(max_length=68, min_length=6, write_only=True)
    tokens = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    
    

    def get_tokens(self, obj):
        user = User.objects.get(email=obj['email'])

        return {
            'refresh': user.tokens()['refresh'],
            'access': user.tokens()['access']
        }

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email', 'password', 'tokens']

    def validate(self, attrs):
        email = attrs.get('email', '')
        password = attrs.get('password', '')
        filtered_user_by_email = User.objects.filter(email=email)
        user = auth.authenticate(email=email, password=password)
        if filtered_user_by_email.exists() and filtered_user_by_email[0].auth_provider != 'email':
            raise AuthenticationFailed(
                detail='Please continue your login using ' + filtered_user_by_email[0].auth_provider)
        if not user:
            raise AuthenticationFailed('Invalid credentials, try again')
        if not user.is_active:
            raise AuthenticationFailed('Account disabled, contact admin')
        if not user.is_verified:
            raise AuthenticationFailed('Email is not verified')
        
        return {
            'email': user.email,
            'tokens': user.tokens,
            
        }

        return super().validate(attrs)
views.py 
class Register(generics.GenericAPIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    serializer_class = UserSerializers
    # renderer_classes = (UserRenderer,)
    def post(self, request):
        user = request.data
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=user)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        user_data = serializer.data
        user = User.objects.get(email=user_data['email'])
        token = RefreshToken.for_user(user).access_token
        current_site = get_current_site(request).domain
        relativeLink = reverse('email-verify')
        absurl = 'http://'+current_site+relativeLink+"?token="+str(token)
        email_body = 'Hi '+user.email + \
            ' Use the link below to verify your email \n' + absurl
        data = {'email_body': email_body, 'to_email': user.email,
                'email_subject': 'Verify your email'}

        Utils.send_email(data)
        return Response(user_data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

# verify the mail that send in the mail box
class VerifyEmail(views.APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    serializer_class = EmailVerificationSerializer
    def get(self, request):
        token = request.GET.get('token')
        try:
            payload = jwt.decode(token, settings.SECRET_KEY, algorithms=["HS256"],type=jwt)
            user = User.objects.get(id=payload['user_id'])
            if not user.is_verified:
                user.is_verified = True
                user.save()
            return Response({'email': 'Successfully activated'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError as identifier:
             return Response({'error': 'Activation Expired'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        except jwt.exceptions.DecodeError as identifier:
            return Response({'error': 'Invalid token'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        
# login apis
class Login(generics.GenericAPIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    serializer_class = UserLoginSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I want to do multiple authentication in django rest framework, I complete the resgistration and I face problems in login the user,  I get email, refresh token and acces token, but I did not get the user type.
when I am login it should verify its coustomer or photographer and it should also return the user for type so, it help is forntens.
please helpto login the user is_customer or is_photographer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not include the fields `is_customer` and `is_photographer` in the login serializer so it will not be returned.

```
# serializers.py
class UserLoginSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # ....
    is_customer = serializers.BooleanField(read_only=True)
    is_photographer = serializers.BooleanField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        fields = ['email', 'password', 'tokens', 'is_customer', 'is_photographer']
```

Comment: it works for me, I add your code thanks.